# data-target not working -- React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple sidebar with dropdowns. I want the dropdowns to be toggled on click. I used data-target property for this. But its not working as expected.

```
<div className="dropdown"> 
    <span className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    <ul id="target" className="collapse">
        <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span className="menuName">Options</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do i accomplish this in react js??

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap library or you are using plain bootstrap library inside your React code?

Comment: plain bootstrap library @MarioNikolaus

Comment: What is ther error you are getting? Btw your span tag is not closed, as well in bootstrap docs there is mention that you should do `Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown`

Comment: Am not getting any errors but the dropdown is not getting toggled @MarioNikolaus

Comment: Is it advisible to use state for just this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **[react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)** as you mentioned in title and also added the tag, then this is the way you can achieve the drop-down.

```
<DropdownButton title="Dropdown" id="bg-vertical-dropdown-1">
   <MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Data attributes should work normally. You have error in your syntax because you are using `class` attribute on all the elements except the first span, instead of `className`.